# How can we create library from Application? (Deriving library/API from Applications)

Tags: oop, design-patterns, api, implementation

My intent is to create a library/API for small scale distributed multi-user game /simulation.

i have created couple of applications using java RMI, i tried to keep them simple and to achieve decoupling and now i want to transform those or want to derive/extract from them a generic template.

Can somebody please shed light that ***How can i come up with library/API***.

(**What could be the possible ways or design patterns, which can help me or kind of most likely procedure/methodology**), so it could be easily usable by other people to create multi-user game.

P.S: I can expect answers to this question but still i want to research for any feedback from technical guru who do all these stuff on every day basis.

load of thanks for any feedback.

jibbylala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What to say, learn library design. There are no other shortcuts.

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-javalibrary/

and read this book (Practical API Design in Java) thoroughly

- http://apress.com/book/view/9781430209737
- http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/Main_Page